# liquibase - Cant get sample to work

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

Im trying to get to run a very simple example in liquibase 1.9.5 (see at the end).

When I run

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=test_sample.xml update
```

I get this error message.

> Migration Failed: ORA-03115:
>   unsupported network datatype or
>   representation

Im using oracle 10g XE 10.2.0.1. As I understand (and googled), this is an error involving 
passing a query to an execute method of a prepared statement, or "something" (guessing my oracle drivers) is deprecated.

My properties file looks like this:

```
#liquibase.properties
driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
classpath: ./classes12.zip
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
username: lb_dev
password: lb_dev
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

file test_sample.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.6"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.6
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.6.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="bob">
        <createTable tableName="department">
            <column name="id" type="int">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="active" type="boolean" defaultValue="1"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the ojdbc14.jar driver instead of classes12.zip